# Multiple declaration of a function make command UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I have 2 files and i want to compile and run them using make command. I created a Makefile named "Makefile". They are compiled but shows an error

```
all: hello
hello: pgm1.o pgm2.o
        g++ pgm1.o pgm2.o -o hello
pgm1.o: pgm1.cpp
        g++ -c pgm1.cpp
pgm2.o: pgm2.cpp
        g++ -c pgm2.cpp
```

They are compiled but shows an error

```
make -f Makefile
g++ pgm1.o pgm2.o -o hello
pgm2.o: In function `print2()':
pgm2.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `print2()'
pgm1.o:pgm1.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

pgm1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pgm2.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        cout<<"Thiss is program 1";
        print2();
        return 0;
}
```

<>pgm2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print2()
{
        cout<<"Thiss is program 2";

}
```

What is that error? How can i rectify it?

Comment: instead of including the #include "pgm2.cpp" could you please declare print2 in the header file pgm2.h and include that one in the pgm1.

Comment: Before diving into make files it may be good idea to get code that compiles using some IDE. Really unclear what you expect to happen when including `.cpp` file with `#include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling both these files into singular output file but your `pgm1.cpp` already contains the function `print2()` by virtue of the line `#include "pgm2.cpp"`...

Possible solutions can be:

1) Remove the include file and instead add a function declaration.

```
void print2();
```

2) As already pointed out create a header file and use include it instead of a .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked